# PostgreSQL 12 authentication error - could not connect to the server

Tags: postgresql, redhat

I have a postgresql 12.2 database on a Red Hat linux 8.4 OS, this database is part of a pgpool cluster.
When I run the following command to check the cluster status:

```
psql -h <dbnode hostname> -p 9999 -U postgres -c 'show pool_nodes'
```

it gives the below error after I enter the password:

[image: Click here for the error]

I am sure that the password is correct, what might be the issue here?
I checked pg_hba.conf file and I have this entry already:

```
host          all         all         <DB_IP_ADDRESS>         md5
```

I tried other methods as well like "trust", but still no luck.

Can someone help me on this please?

Comment: If you still get a password error when using 'trust', then you are not really using 'trust'.

Comment: Are you connecting to an actual database, or to pgpool itself which emulating a database?